# how to make coordinates relative to a canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I have a 600x1000 pixel screen and my player starts near the bottom left. His x and y coordinates are (50, 900). I'm drawing this player to a canvas and using 

`canvas.translate(-player.getX()+GAMEWIDTH/2, 0)` 
to make sure the player stays in the middle of the screen with respect to the x-axis. This results in my player being rendered at (300, 900), however the player's x and y coordinates remain at (50, 900). This presents an issue because I need the player's coordinates to be the same as his rendered location because I use touch events on the player's collision rectangles to move him around. Is there any way to make my screen's coordinates be relative to my canvas coordinates so that my player's coordinates correspond to where they actually get rendered? Or is there maybe another way to do it?

Comment: When you do the touch event hit detection shouldn't you always pass it player.getX()+GAMEWIDTH/2. The only way you can make the coordinates relative, is if you apply the transform yourself. I typically keep a relative.x and global.x for things like this. The relative would be the 50 in your case, and the global would be the 50 + GAMEWIDTH/2.

Comment: thanks this put me on the right track. I got what I wanted by adding "player.getX()-GAMEWIDTH/2" to my "recentTouchX" in my "Input" class. I thought the issue was with the location of my collision rectangles but in actuality it was with my TouchListener which listens to the View and not the Canvas. Before any translation, my View and Canvas were the same, but after the translation they weren't,  this extra line of code makes up for the translation. Put your comment as an answer and dat upvote and check is yours :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The touchEvents are always based on the the x & y relative to the canvas element itself. Since the view is centering the character by translating the view `canvas.translate(-player.getX() + GAMEWIDTH/2 , 0);` you need to also apply that translation to the touchEvent. You can do it in the touch handler itself, or you could store both a relative and absolute position for the items in your game world. This will become more important if items become nested in one another. This is typically done by storing the parent element of a sprite/object.

```
//example of how I usually handle object hierarchy
this._x = this.x + this.parent._x;
this._y = this.y + this.parent._y;
```

the canvas/stage would also store it's center as a ._x and ._y which would be the parent of the the objects added, this way when you generate the global position to do your touchEvents against instead of passing in the .x or .y you would pass in the ._x and ._y which are already translated by the GAMEWIDTH/2.